# New method in plone.app.textfield.widget.py

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I have to extend the

```
class RichTextWidget(TextAreaWidget):
```

from the package plone.app.textfield.widget.py

I need an additional method:

```
def new_method(self):
    do_anything...
```

How can I achieve this?

I added some code in my existing overrides.zcml, but this has no effect:

```
<z3c:widgetTemplate
  layer="z3c.form.interfaces.IFormLayer"
  mode="display"
  template="widget_display.pt"
  widget=".widget.RichTextWidget"
/>
```

In my custom widget.py I tried this:

```
from plone.app.textfield.widget import RichTextWidget as DefaultView
class RichTextWidget(DefaultView):
    def new_method(self):
        return 'foo'
```

Comment: Where do you call/use `new_method`? in a custim widget template? What would you like to achieve? I mean what is your expected result?

Comment: You may have better luck posting questions on our forum, https://community.plone.org (more eyeballs), though I will post a link on the forum to your question here.

Comment: OK thx. Moved to: https://community.plone.org/t/plone-upgrade-4-1-4-3-richtext-did-you-mean-raw-or-output